# How can a Script be periodically invoked from the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

In a [script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/how-can-i-do-a-one-time-initialization) I try to get the coordinates of a head tracker and to change the current scenes camera. The script is wired as shown in this image:

[image]

Unfortunatly the script is only called once. How can I setup the Sensor/Controller to invoke it periodically (preferably after a frame has been rendered)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the delay sensor with the repeat setting checked:
[image]

Comment: and the default delay is 60 per seconds, cool

Answer (score 6):

I had to click the small button (highlighted) and set the frequency to 1.

The option is called [bpy.types.Sensor.use_pulse_true_level](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.Sensor.html#bpy.types.Sensor.use_pulse_true_level)

[image]