# How do I create a haptic interface?

Tags: modeling, interface

I would like to use a data glove to move objects and get feedback from them. Is there a plug in product for this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the glove is connected to your computer, assuming it works with USB there're two common approaches (I don't know a finished plugin).

One is to use a server for the [OSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) protocol and receive the data in a python module in Blender. I used this for integrating a Kinect Sensor. 
An example integration you find in this project's [Bloop NUI zip file](http://dm.tzi.de/bloop/).

Another method would be to use the API of the glove (if available) and include this as a library in Blender to poll data. This I've used to read head tracking data from an Oculus Rift.

See [How can I do a one-time Initialization?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/how-can-i-do-a-one-time-initialization) for an example on invoking methods of an external library.

If the glove comes without an API you could interface with [hdiapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/)  and analyze the data.